# Hover more than one element at the same time

Tags: css, hover

I've searched over SO and even found some related posts, but none of them seemed to fix my problem.

Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
            <div class="work">
                <a href="#">
                    <h2>
                        Work #1
                    </h2>
                    <p>
                        subtitle 1
                    </p>
                    <img src="img/img1.png" />
                </a>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.work {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.work h2 {
    font-family: Cambria, serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    letter-spacing: -0.2;
}
.work p {
    font-family: Cambria, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    letter-spacing: -0.2;
}
.work img {
    margin-top: 12px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
/* links */
.work a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.work a:hover {
    color: #FF8000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Even though it works, I would like that the `<h2>` and `<p>` were different colors when not hovered. For what the code is now they are default black, but that's not what I need.

If I set a color on `<h2>` or `<p>` this color sort of overlaps the hover color and I don't understand why.

I know this is a very simple matter, but can't seem to cover it. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the issue? It is unclear what you want to do?

Comment: h2 and p both are in a tag thats why they are having same color even on hover. you want to give different different color to h2 and p tag?

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/0wLp8a6b/2/

Comment: I have updated my comment so check and let me know so i can post as answer..thanx

Comment: @ketan @Leo I need both `<h2>` and `<p>` to change their state at the same time when I hover any of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you...

HTML:

```
    <div class="work">
        <a href="#">
            <h2>
                Work #1
            </h2>
            <p>
                subtitle 1
            </p>
            <img src="img/img1.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
        .work {
            margin-top: 40px;
        }
        .work h2 {
            font-family: Cambria, serif;
            font-size: 24px;
            letter-spacing: -0.2;
        }
        .work p {
            font-family: Cambria, serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 24px;
            letter-spacing: -0.2;
        }
        .work img {
            margin-top: 12px;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        /* links */
        .work a:link, a:visited, a:active {
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .work h2:hover {
            color: #FF8000;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .work p:hover {
            color: green;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```